# Is there a difference between a カーニバル and an お祭り?

Tags: meaning, words, kanji, katakana

Is there a difference between a カーニバル and an  お祭り? I researched the terms on Jisho. Does it have to do with the duration or type of the activities?  Thank you.

Comment: carnival と festival は違いますもんね・・

Comment: There is an apparent difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

祭り refers to festivals in general; it can refer to all sorts of festivals all over the world, religious or non-religious.

カーニバル specifically refers to [carnivals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnival) celebrated in Christian countries, or events derived from that. It's also commonly associated with Samba since Rio's Carnival is world-famous. Japan is not a Christian country, so there is no traditional Japanese カーニバル. Simply, if a foreign event is called "XYZ Carnival" in English, it is called "XYZカーニバル" in Japanese, too.

Comment: 40 years as an American and I've never heard of a Christian carnival.

Comment: @By137: see  Mardi Gras

Answer (score 2):

日本でカーニバルと言われると、

1. narutoさんが言われている様に、復活祭の前に行われる欧州・南米等のカーニバル
2. 日本で南米のカーニバルを模して、サンバ系の音楽と共にパレードするイベント
3. その他、パレードが同時に行われるイベント（maybe same as tuomo's explanation)

といったことを想像します。

お祭りと言われますと、風習としてある期間に実施されるお祭りから、
学校や会社で実施される皆んなで騒いで盛り上がる行事もお祭りと呼んでしまいます。

このお祭りという言葉には、カーニバルも含まれています。

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not the duration. In Japan, as the carnivals are typically more like short events with their theme being the original carnival, and, as Japanese "don't have time" their matsuris, while being short [maybe 0.5 ... 3 days], may last longer than the Japanese "carnivals", which tend to be [very] short versions of the original ones, with e.g. the Rio Samba Carnival lasting for 5 days.

In general, I think it is simply about if the event is a "Japanese carnival" or a "Foreign carnival".

But, in case you live in Japan and watch ItteQ, their 世界の祭り covers [or maybe "covered"] also events which would not normally not be referred to as carnivals.

Comment: it depends on the theme?

Comment: I think more like, a "matsuri" / "carnival" probably having born from natural needs / way in which people want to relax and interact [thinking this due to the similarity of such events in countries, with the events having been established long before any interaction between those countries]. But, "matsuri" would be an event that has "local roots", i.e. based on local traditions, and "carnival" an imported one, even if both may involve similar activities [like dancing, drinking and in some way or another making a fool of oneself typically in order to prove one is part of the group]

Comment: Please add that to your answer! They don't appear to be the same thing.

Comment: I'll try, but needs editing, too...

Comment: A carnival may be bigger with a different theme...

Comment: OK, maybe you correct / make an additional reply, as I didn't quite understand. Yes, Japan was not as "metropolized" before as it is today, but not were the other countries either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98991/discussion-between-jack-and-tuomo).